# CodeIgniter flashdata does not die after a single request

Tags: php, codeigniter

As describe in CodeIgniter Documentation, `flashdata` are session which are alive only within a request, and after that they die.

Now I have used this mechanism for my login process, however, it fails. Whenever I visit the page, that certain `flashdata` is alive.

I have set a `flashdata` on the occasions that the login `email/pass` is wrong, and the return to the login page, I then set a conditional which checks if the flashdata is set, then show an error. Now, every time I visit the login page it shows login failed error. Why?

Here is the login's page conditional which checks for the flashdata availability (in login.php view file)

```
if($this->session->flashdata("login-result") == 0)
{
    show_fail("رمز عبور یا رایانامه اشتباه می باشد.");  
}
```

I also have put the `echo()` code to see if the flashdata is ever set, which shows the proper value:

```
echo ($this->session->flashdata("login-result") );
```

And here is the login conditional which I have used to set the flashdata:

```
// go with regular registration 
$this->db->where("email", $this->input->post("email"));
$this->db->where("password", md5($this->input->post("password")));
$this->db->from("users");
$login_result = $this->db->count_all_results();
if($login_result == 0)
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata("login-result", 0);
    redirect(base_url("access/login")); 
}
else if($login_result > 0)
{
    redirect("panel/home"); 
}
```

Comment: You used it correctly in your code, so why do you keep calling it flashcard??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be that you assigned your FLASHDATA the value of `0`, which is ok a number, but in PHP 0 also means FALSE, which is the regular return value of a flashdata not set.

So try giving it a truish value:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata("login-result", 1);
```

and you'll see that

```
if(!$this->session->flashdata("login-result"))
{
  show_fail("رمز عبور یا رایانامه اشتباه می باشد.");  
}
```

will work.

If you want to keep the `0`, use a *strict equality* check:

```
if($this->session->flashdata("login-result") === 0)
```

So that it will check that flashdata is the same value **and type**.

See the [types comparison chart](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for more details

Answer (score 0):

try using`$this->session->set_flashdata('your message')`

Comment: You might want to explain why your answer is (or might be) correct, to help the OP or future readers understand your reasoning.